# One Gives Me An Error, The Other Does Not. Range.ClearContents

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop the rows and delete them if a certain cell has Zero

```
Range(Cells(rCol, rRow), Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents
```

This gives me an error:  Cannot change part of a merged cell. There are 0 merged cells in the entire workbook.

```
Range("C11:N11").ClearContents
```

This is the same thing as above, but the variables are replaced with integer values and works!

HOW?

Comment: You got the Col and Rol inverted. First is Row, second is Col

Comment: Firstly, `Cells()` has row as the first argument, not the second.